# Show Data of multiple tables without joining them in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in C#. Here I display some football players through a Data Source. I have a table Players, in this table are also the teamId's and countryId's of each player. For example, countryId 1 stands for Belgium. Those id's are linked with the correct countryname in an other table "Countries".

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to display the country name instead of the id without joining the tables, because I need to get a Player-object out of the DataGridView to delete, edit, ...

I have to use LINQ and I'm practically hardcoding everything.

Code of PlayerForm(With DGV)

```
public partial class PlayersForm : Form
{
    public PlayersForm(int id)
    {
        int teamId = id;
        InitializeComponent();
        DataClassesFPDataContext db = new DataClassesFPDataContext();
        var players = db.Players.ToList();
        dgvPlayersPerTeam.DataSource = players;
        var playersTeam = from player in players
                          where player.Team_TeamId == teamId
                          select player;
        dgvPlayersPerTeam.DataSource = playersTeam.ToList();

    }
}
```

Now I just display all the info of the players as you can see down below. (Can't use pictures in post because of reputation.)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byl4uvHVXWkYU3AtQWtGdW1taFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: are you familiar with the `new` key word when using a linq statement.. you can create list of fields that you need using the `new` key word followed by what you want to call the field..then rebind it to the `DGV` if you are not familiar with that.. then what's stopping you from creating a linq query to return the the fields / values that you need...[101 Linq Samples in C#](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) I would highly suggest downloading this .. it will shed some much needed light

Comment: My colleague made it like this, but you make a new type this way. Now I can't extract one player-object from the DGV.

Comment: it's very difficult to understand what you are saying in your last comment also just because you are assigning the datasource, you can't stop there you need to bind that datasource to the DGV by calling your `drgPlayyersPerTeam.DataBind();` where are you doing the binding

Comment: I don't use databinding. But I solved my own problem after some more research. But thanks a lot for trying to help me!

Comment: either post your solution or remove the question because in it's current state it does nobody any justice

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question. I needed CellFormatting. Now the countryId gets changed thanks to this method.

```
private void dgvPlayersPerTeam_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Country_CountryId" &&
            e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
            dgv["Country_CountryId", e.RowIndex].Value is int)
        {
            DataClassesFPDataContext db = new DataClassesFPDataContext();
            var countries = db.Countries.ToList();
            int countryId = (int)dgv["Country_CountryId", e.RowIndex].Value;
            string countryFull = (from country in countries
                                  where country.CountryId == countryId
                                  select country.Full).First().ToString();

            e.Value = countryFull;
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
```